# What does a Convergent Sequence of Improper Integrals Tell You About the Convergence of the Integrands?

Tags: sequences-and-series, improper-integrals, uniform-convergence

Suppose that $F_{N}(x)$ is a sequence of continous functions defined on $[0, \infty)$ with the property that $\int_{0}^{\infty} F_{N}(x) \cdot dx < \infty$ for all $N$ and further that $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} F_{N}(x) \cdot dx = L < \infty$. What can be said about $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} F_{N}(x)$? Must $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} F_{N}(x)$ converge (at least pointwise) to a function, $F(x)$ on $[0, \infty)$? Can we make a stronger conclusion that $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} F_{N}(x)$ must converge *uniformly* to a *continuous* function on, $F(x)$ on $[0, \infty)$? Must this function $F(x)$ also be integrable over $[0, \infty)$, i.e. in $L^{1}([0, \infty))$?

Comment: No, $F_N$ need not converge pointwise.  Find a counterexample where two functions alternate ... $F_1, F_2, F_1, F_2, F_1, F_2, \dots$.

Comment: I see; you mean two functions alternate with $F_{1} \neq F_{2}$, but $\int_{0}^{\infty} F_{1}(x) \cdot dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} F_{2}(x) \cdot dx$, correct?